# Polling in py-spy flame graph of celery worker

Tags: celery, python-multithreading, gil

I am debugging a celery worker running in a docker container.

- Celery version: 5.2.7
- broker: rabbitmq
- results backend: redis
- profiling: py-spy 0.3.14
- docker: 24.0.7

I launch the celery worker with:

```
celery -A app.client worker --pool=threads -l debug --concurrency=1
```

I understand that this will launch one main and one worker thread.

Here is the [py-spy flame graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbIYk.png).

I am currently reading some books about concurrency, so I'm trying to understand what is going on under the hood but there's a couple of points that I don't understand about the graph. I also want to make sure I do not have obvious bottlenecks in my application.

- Why is `poll (kombu/utils/eventio.py:83)` represented that much (exactly 50.00%, just like `run (threading.py:953)`)? From my understanding, since I don't use any kind of rate limit in celery, polling should not be blocking and should return immediately.
- Why is time spend in line 81 and in line 83 of `concurrent/futures/thread.py` represented separately?

I am mainly trying to understand if the two blocks `poll (kombu/utils/eventio.py:83)` and `concurrent/futures/thread.py:81` are blocking and I should worry about them or if and why they are an artefact of how `py-spy` deals with this particular celery setup.

I tried profiling with `py-spy` and did not expect these blocks, except for the actual worker logic block.

I tried looking at the source code pointed to by `py-spy`, but still did not understand what would lead `py-spy` to represent execution that way.